# warning attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Steps to reproduce -

1. Open Modal view controller on tap of button of Root View controller.
2. In Modal view controller - On button, create segue to show popover view controller.
3. Tap on button to see Popover view controller.
4. Now multiple taps on screen to dismiss the popover view controller, it directly redirects to Rootview controller.(dismissing the Modal view controller).

Another approach -

1. Create IBAction to show popover view controller.
2. Tap on button to see Popover view controller.
3. This time it just dismiss the pop view controller. (Not redirecting to RootView controller)

Why this weird behavior when your showing Popover view controller in two different ways?
I am working on already developed big project and now its not possible for me to go ahead with second approach.
Please help me to find out the better way to resolve this.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to create a delegate method in your Modal view controller.
After your popover view controller dismissed, then call your Modal view controller delegate method to dismiss as well.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    ModalViewControllerDelegate.dismissView;
}];
```